# Log4Net log file not being written when using WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, log4net

I am trying to use log4net to track possible errors in my project.

I am using a WCF service, a client and a server lib.

The issue I am having is that whenever I run the project, and I want to test this, It will create the  log files in the correct directory but It never write on it, not even if I put Logger.Info("test"); in the first call.

I have check a lot a sites and I have try a lot of things and nothing seems to work.

log4net.onfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="GeneralAppender" />
    </root>
    <logger name="GeneralLogger">
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="GeneralAppender" />
    </logger>
    <appender name="GeneralAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\mylog.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="SIze" />
      <datePattern value="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.ff" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] - [%logger] %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

this file is locate in the service project and in the library
both files have set the "Copy to Output Directory" property to "Copy if newer"

I have modifify the AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

The way to decalre the variable is:

```
static readonly log4net.ILog _Logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

The way in which I use the logger is the following:

```
_Logger.Info("some info");
_Logger.Error("This is an error", Exception);
```

Comment: have you confirmed using a tool like procmon from SysInternals that it's not a permissions issue with the WCF app trying to write to your desktop?

Comment: The problem may be that you have config sections defined, which isn't necessary when the config is in it's own file. Run with log4net in debug mode with `<log4net debug=true>` and check the Output window for any problems.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I add the debug mode and checked the output windows and it seems to be an error but it gives me a guide to keep working..

I will let you know if I have any further issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this issue before; try adding the following line of code to your service startup.

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

It's part of the log4net.Config namespace.

Comment: That's not necessary when using assembly attributes

Comment: Thanks Allan!
I just try that but It does not log me anything

Comment: Hmm ... it's odd that it creates the file and writes nothing; as the only other issue I've seen like this was due to permissions with the account the Windows service was running under. But if it creates the file, then it must have permissions. I tried log level "ALL" on one of mine and it works. Can you try logging to c:\TEMP\ and see if that makes a difference?